# How to increase line padding in Geany IDE?

Tags: c++, editor, geany

I am using **geany**, and I need to increase line padding, ie, space between consecutive lines.

For example, in sublime text, we can change padding by:

```
"line_padding_bottom": 2,
"line_padding_top": 2
```

How do we do it for **Geany**? I tried many options and menus, but there doesn't seem to be an option!

Here is an image illustrating the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmAAj.png

Comment: I think You can't add padding to font but as a workaround You can try to use different font with more padding like Latin Modern Mono.

Answer (score 14):

Go to Tools->Configuration Files->filetypes.common and search for line_height, and make as line_height=2;2;

Answer (score 13):

Good answer, but you also need to uncomment [styling] line, if commented (mine was). So, configuration in filetypes.common should look like this:

```
[styling]
line_height=2;2;
```

Comment: In my case, the whole file was messed up with comments from geany etc. I had to remove everything except the two lines and then it started working.

Comment: No need to clean-out the whole filetypes.common file. Just remove the comment characters in front of the [styling] and line_height lines.